# How do i get 100% battery charge back with Samsung battery life extender?

Tags: laptop, battery

I use a samsung netbook which i have been using for almost four months now.
I have been using the samsung battery life extender since the first time i used the laptop.

I decided to turn it off due to some power issues but the laptop does not charge to 100%, the highest it gets is 92% even when shut down and plugged in for hours.
The battery charge remains at 92% even with battery life extender disabled.

How do i get 100% back?

Comment: Probably an option in the BIOS to change between longer battery life or better performance (thus reducing battery life). This is probably turned on so the battery never charges to 100% because this can reduce battery life.

Comment: It might be worth running the battery down to as close to 0% as you can get it, then charging it back up again. This can sometimes help with calibration issues.

Comment: Most BIOSses on a laptop have a calibrate function hidden somewhere that you can run. This should fix the issue.

Comment: Note that there are two kinds of "battery extenders".  One kind "throttles" the system so that is consumes power at a lower rate.  The other prevents the battery from fully charging.  On my Sony Vista box the "throttle" function is more obvious and easier to find than the other function.

Comment: @James I run the battery down with the battery calibration option in the bios and this time i got a charge of 98%, personally i think its ok but I'm concerned about the fact that it does not get a 100% charge.

Comment: @James i tried the second time and i got a 100 now. Thanks really appreciated